# 2 different instance of axios mock having returning an error of axios.default is not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, axios, jestjs, ts-jest

In my function named eventController. An axios call has implemented in two ways
The 1st one is on this code

```
axios.post(
           `${url}/API1`,
           {
              data:'data for API1'
           }
        )
```

Then this is the 2nd

```
 await axios({
     method: 'POST',
     url: `${url}/API2`,
     data: {
         data:'data for API2'
     }
  })
```

2 different axios calls in one function/controller

I'm assigned in implementing a unit test for this using jest in typescript

So what I did so far is this

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
   post: jest
      .fn()
      .mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 }) 
}));

    it("should work", async () => {
      const req = {body: {
     data: 'data for API'
}}
      const response = await eventController(req);

      expect(response.status).toBe(200);
   });
```

I mock the 1st axios call with .post method but when doing it w/ the second one using the default axios module I have received this error

```
  TypeError: (0 , axios_1.default) is not a function
```

I've tried to implement this way also but both don't seem to work
This:

```
    jest.mock('axios', () => ({
   __esModule: true,
   default: jest.fn(),
   post: jest
      .fn()
      .mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 }) 
}));
```

and this:

```
jest.mock('axios', () => ({
           __esModule: true,
           default: { 
post: jest
              .fn()
              .mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 })
    },
          
        }));
```

Hoping someone can help me on this one. This is the versions of the library I'm currently using

- "jest": "^27.0.6"
- babel-jest": "^27.0.6"
- "axios": "^0.21.4",
- @types/jest": "^27.0.0",
- "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and without passing the `factory` argument, let the jest mocks a module with an auto-mocked version. And, there is no `__mocks__` directory.

You need to handle the TS types for `axios` function and `axios.get()` method after mocking, use type cast to do this.

Note: I use a simple string as the mock resolved value which **does not match** the `AxiosResponse` interface.

E.g.

`main.ts`:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'http://localhost:3000';
export async function main() {
  const res1 = await axios.post(`${url}/API1`, {
    data: 'data for API1',
  });
  console.log('res1: ', res1);
  const res2 = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `${url}/API2`,
    data: {
      data: 'data for API2',
    },
  });
  console.log('res2: ', res2);
}
```

`main.test.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './main';
import axios from 'axios';

jest.mock('axios');

const axiosMock = axios as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios>;
const axiosPostMock = axios.post as jest.MockedFunction<typeof axios.post>;

test('should pass', async () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(axios)).toBe(true);
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(axios.post)).toBe(true);
    axiosPostMock.mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data 1');
    axiosMock.mockResolvedValueOnce('fake data 2' as any);
    await main();
});
```

Test result:

```
 PASS  stackoverflow/76407602/main.test.ts (38.236 s)
  ✓ should pass (48 ms)

  console.log
    res1:  fake data 1

      at stackoverflow/76407602/main.ts:8:11

  console.log
    res2:  fake data 2

      at stackoverflow/76407602/main.ts:16:11

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        41.384 s
```

Comment: This working in axios.post method but in default axios export I received an error `Property 'mockResolvedValueOnce' does not exist on type 'AxiosStatic'`. Im using typesript by the way. Do you know how I can set the correct type for this?

Comment: @GabAgoncillo Updated answer, you should take care of the TS type.